# Is it OK to apply multiple BEM elements to an html element's class?

Tags: html, css, bem

I am structuring the CSS in my web application according to the [BEM convention](http://getbem.com/).

I have a block called `item` and 3 elements: `item__section`, `item__title` and `item__description`.

I am using these BEM classes as follows:

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="item__section item__title"> ... </div>
  <div class="item__section item__description"> ... </div>
</div>
```

The `item__section` element class contains style that we reuse between elements.

**Is this valid BEM or should I create a modifier for `item__section` for each kind of section(title and description)?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's absolutely valid and is called `mix`:

- https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/#mix
- https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#mixes

Comment: the above code is not a mix , you shouldn't use two elements of the same block in the same tag

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you should.
You could add mixin like:

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="item__section u-title"> ... </div>
  <div class="item__section u-description"> ... </div>
</div>
```

but don't use two elements of the same block in the same tag because you can end up with specificity problems